# How to set the Header and footer in Jquery TableTools using MVC4

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using jquery tabletools to export m reports.My Boss ask me to set the header and Footer in report.In header part i want to display  the  another table that contain values.Anyone Pls hELP mE

Here is my coding

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    var Table = $('#SalesCollectionReportList').dataTable({

        "bJQueryUI": "true",

        "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ilp>',
        // copy, print, excel, with select all
        "oLanguage": {
            "sInfo": "Displaying <b>_TOTAL_</b> records for <b> Biocare</b>"
        },
        "oTableTools": {
            // "sRowSelect": "multi",
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",

            "aButtons": ["copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf"]
        },

        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "aaSorting": []



    });


});
```

This table  want to display in Header part of the document

```
        <table id="one">
            <colgroup style="width: 15%"></colgroup>
            <colgroup style="width: 35%"></colgroup>
            <colgroup style="width: 15%"></colgroup>
            <colgroup style="width: 35%"></colgroup>

            <tr>
                <td style="width:50%">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:5%">
                                @Html.Label("Company Name :")
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:20%">
                                @Infoline.Biocare.UI.Web.Controllers.AdminController.GlobalCompany.CompanyName
                            </td> 

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                             <td style="width:5%">
                                @Html.Label("Address :")
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:20%">
                                 @Infoline.Biocare.UI.Web.Controllers.AdminController.GlobalCompany.Address1 <br />

                            </td> 
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>

                <td style="width:50%">
                        <table>
                        <tr>

                            <td style="width:45%; text-align:right">
                               @Html.Label("Date :")
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:5%">
                               @DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString()
                            </td> 

                        </tr>

                         <tr>

                            <td style="width:45%; text-align:right">
                                @Html.Label("Page No :")
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:5%">
                               1
                            </td> 

                        </tr>


                         <tr>

                            <td style="width:45%; text-align:right">

                            </td>
                            <td style="width:5%">

                            </td> 

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>




            </tr>



            @Html.Hidden("CompanyId", Infoline.Biocare.UI.Web.Controllers.AdminController.GlobalCompany.CompanyId)
        </table>
```